# Менять ширину одного блока при изменении другого

Tags: jquery

Нужно менять ширину блока `.middle` в зависимости от ширины блока `.right`. Сделать при загрузке страницы получается, но нужно, чтобы скрипт выполнялся постоянно (отслеживал ширину правого блока и менял ширину среднего блока). Не могу понять, как сюда `.on()` прикрутить.
[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/s9zdxx0y/1/)

Comment: В JS нет такой возможности — отслеживать изменение размеров отдельного блока, можно отследить только изменение размеров окна.
И вообще лучше такие вещи CSS-ом делать.

Comment: Bars, на чистом css проблематично или опыта маловато. Дело в том, что в среднем блоке есть блок формы поиска, который должен занимать оставшееся свободное место.В общем, ширина левого и правого блоков меняется в зависимости от содержимого, а средний блок должен занять оставшееся свободное пространство. Обёртка трёх блоков имеет фиксированную ширину